# css sibling selector help needed for Markdown stylesheet

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am using a CSS stylesheet from a markdown editor that has the following CSS.

```
p strong {
font-size: larger;
}
```

In the rendered HTML the titles that are always in the form

```
<p><strong>title</strong></p>
```

for example

```
<p><strong>Example of adding a new persistent rule</strong></p>
```

And then the usual paragraphs that i have some words in bold are represent as:

```
<p> text text text <strong>red text</strong> text text <strong>red tezt</strong></p>
```

I would like to change or edit the CSS so that only the text within the `<p><strong>title</strong></p>` has it's text shown in a different color.

Can anyone help with the needed CSS please. I tried various sibling selector combinations but nothing worked. Often in Chrome dev tools the stuff i tried like `p+strong {color: red;}` was grayed out and has no effect.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does your implementation of Markdown not support headings or something? I don't see why you couldn't just use headings here, since these are clearly what they are. Not just paragraphs of bold text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a sibling selector, but a (direct) [child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors)

As such, you should use:

`p > strong`

> The > combinator separates two selectors and matches only those
>   elements matched by the second selector that are direct children of
>   elements matched by the first. By contrast, when two selectors are
>   combined with the descendant selector, the combined selector
>   expression matches those elements matched by the second selector for
>   which there exists an ancestor element matched by the first selector,
>   regardless of the number of "hops" up the DOM.

A sibling selector is one which identifies DOM nodes at the same level which follow one another. Here your `strong` element is *within* your `p`

```css
p + strong {
  text-decoration: underline; /* directly adjacent sibling (wont apply) */
}
p ~ strong {
  font-style: italic; /* adjacent sibling (wont apply) */
}
p > strong { /* (direct) child (applies) */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>text text text <strong>red text</strong> text text <strong>red tezt</strong>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the codepen example below

http://codepen.io/jmonit/pen/wBrWgW

```
p strong{ color:red; font-size: larger; }
```

You dont anything different the same css as you are useing will work for changing the color? In the link i have used markdown code to generate the paragraph and the strong tag. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As SW4 mentions, the way you're using sibling selectors is incorrect because the `strong` elements are *children* of the `p` elements, not siblings. In other words, the `strong` elements are represented by `p > strong`, not `p + strong`.

You appear to be looking to style a `strong` element differently when

1. it is the only `strong` element within this `p`, and
2. all the text is contained in this `strong` element; there is no other bare text within the `p`.

The first part can be achieved using either `p > strong:only-child` or `p > strong:only-of-type`. But because [text nodes and other non-element nodes are always ignored by structural pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#structural-pseudos), this would also target the element in this example:

```
<p>text text <strong>red text</strong> text text</p>
```

Which you probably don't want. Unfortunately, the second part cannot be done using just a CSS selector for this reason.

As I mentioned in my comment, you can very easily avoid all of this by just putting section titles in proper heading elements instead, [which Markdown supports](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#header), and target those headings. But if your implementation of Markdown *doesn't* support headings for whatever reason, or you can't modify the Markdown content, then you may be out of luck unless you write a script to detect these elements and either give them class names or swap them out for actual headings on-the-fly.