# select :only-child only if there is no additional content

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way, using *css selectors* (no javascript), to select a child element only if there is *no additional content*?

I want to achieve the following:

```html
<style>p b:only-child { color: red }</style>
<p><b>this should be red</b></p>
<p><b>this</b> should be not</p>
<p><b>this</b> <i>neither</i></p>
```

The [`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) selector works for the third line, but not for the second. See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oem5nujp/1/).

Comment: might be useful, though looks tedious: http://lea.verou.me/2011/01/styling-children-based-on-their-number-with-css3/

Comment: Basically, no. CSS styles what is there, not what isn't.

Comment: @MarcB I read that article. `:only-child` is in fact a shorthand for `:first-child:last-child` (or `:nth-child(1):nth-last-child(1)` as Lea writes). That doesn't work :( . I hope @Paulie_D is not right...

Comment: Oddly enough, this is just the pure Y version of [this XY question from earlier today](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272627/css-sibling-selector-help-needed-for-markdown-stylesheet). All I had to do was refer to my answer there in order to answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the spec, under the section on [structural pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#structural-pseudos) it says:

> Selectors introduces the concept of *structural pseudo-classes* to permit selection based on extra information that lies in the document tree but cannot be represented by other simple selectors or combinators.
>
> Standalone text and other non-element nodes are not counted when calculating the position of an element in the list of children of its parent. When calculating the position of an element in the list of children of its parent, the index numbering starts at 1.

The only selector that takes into account the presence of text nodes (for a *non-match*, oddly enough) is `:empty`. All other structural pseudo-classes including `:only-child` do not take them into account.